# How to create dashed lines/arrows in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, line-art

I'm looking for help on how to create the dashed lines and arrows in the example below.

[image]

In this example you can see the arrows, which follow a curved path, yet, the stripes remain in perfect "parallel" order. I did not manage to figure out how to do this in Illustrator myself. I created a pattern with parallel stripes, but as soon as there is a curve you can imagine what happens, it gets distorted/tries to fill out/maintain the pattern which does not produce the intended result at all.

Is there actually an easy way to do this? Or do I have to Move/Copy/Rotate "every single line" individually? Here is a quick example of how it looks right now in my file, I would very much want to get the result in the example.

[image: My result so far]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a dashed path and define the stroke weight + dash and gap sizes

[image]

Comment: That was simpler than I expected, didn't think to try that out! This works with every path, right? Thank you anyway for the quick and easy answer!

Comment: Yes, with every path. Glad to help.